# How to delete all text inside a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a div that looks like this.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="thumbs">
        Text 1
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-business-icons/128/stack-128.png"/>
        <div></div>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <div>
            <p>Text 3</p>
            <div><p>Text 4</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to delete all text inside the `div` with the class `thumbs`. I tried this, but unfortunately, it only delete "Text 1" and not the others.

```
<script>
    $(".main .thumbs").contents().filter(function () {
         return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).remove();
</script>
```

> EDIT : I tried every single suggestion you gived to me. And most of
>   them are working, but I stuck with haim770 solution

Comment: tack `.find('p').empty()` on to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `contents()` would only return the direct (child) nodes of each `.thumb`. You can either gather them all recursively, or use `find('*')` to fetch them:

```
function removeTextNodes()
{
  $(this).contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).remove();
}

$(".main .thumbs").find('*').addBack().each(removeTextNodes);
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjopLuxb/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @haim770 ! I tried your solution and it works!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all you want is the image left you could do:

```
$(".main .thumbs").html(function(){
   return $(this).find('img');
});
```

Result would be:

```
<div class="thumbs">
   <img src="...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> delete all text inside the `div`

Do you want to delete ALL the text nodes (not just the immediate children) while preserving the elements?

```
$(".main .thumbs").find("*").addBack().contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

Explanation:

1. `.find("*")` finds all the descendant elements of `.thumbs`
2. [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) adds `.thumbs` to the collection (so now we have `.thumbs` *and* all its descendants)
3. `.contents()` gets all the nodes of the collection (so it gets ALL the nodes of `.thumbs`, not just the immediate children nodes)
4. You already know how to filter to only the text nodes and remove them

Comment: Looks correct to me, don't know why someone did a fly-by-downvote of everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function:

```js
var removeTextNodes = function(el) {
    el.contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).remove();

    el.contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType !== 3;
    }).each(function() {
        removeTextNodes($(this));
    });
}
removeTextNodes($('#foo'));
```

```css
#bar1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
#bar2 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
    first
    <div id="bar1">
        jumps over a lazy dog!
    </div>
    second
    <div id="bar2">
  another jumps over a lazy dog!
    </div>
    third
</div>
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Hulothe/UK9xU/172/).

Comment: This also appears to work and no reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Recursive solution

```js
function clearText(elem){
    console.log({elemt: elem})
      if(elem.firstChild && elem.firstChild.nodeType == 3) {
         elem.firstChild.nodeValue = '';
      } 
      
      if(elem.children.length) {
       $.each(elem.children, function(){
           clearText(this); 
           });
      }
      
   
}

clearText($(".main .thumbs")[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="thumbs">
        Text 1
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-business-icons/128/stack-128.png"/>
        <div></div>
        <p>Text 2</p>
        <div>
            <p>Text 3</p>
            <div><p>Text 4</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to remove all child elements text too:

```
$(".thumbs, .thumbs *")
    .contents()
    .filter(function(){
        return this.nodeType === 3;
    })
    .remove();
```

Comment: This also looks correct and appears to work. Don't know why it was downvoted?

Comment: @Xotic750 I guess somebody downvoted all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

In any modern browser you can use the following POJS.

See [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

IE8+

See [TreeWalker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) and [Document.createTreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker)

IE9+

```js
var firstThumbs = document.querySelector('.thumbs');
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(firstThumbs, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
  acceptNode: function(node) {
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
  }
}, false);

setTimeout(function() {
  while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    treeWalker.currentNode.textContent = '';
  }
}, 3000);
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="thumbs">
    Text 1
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-business-icons/128/stack-128.png" />
    <div></div>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <div>
      <p>Text 3</p>
      <div>
        <p>Text 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or yet another jQuery solution.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.thumbs')
    .first()
    .find('*')
    .addBack()
    .contents()
    .filter(function(index, node) {
      return node.nodeType == 3;
    })
    .remove();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="thumbs">
    Text 1
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-business-icons/128/stack-128.png" />
    <div></div>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <div>
      <p>Text 3</p>
      <div>
        <p>Text 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used jQuery 2 which is IE9+